# JQUERY getting ID value of LI element from nested ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML code**

```
<ul id='orgCat'>
    <li parent-id="0" li-id="16">Anthropology Department</li>
    <li parent-id="16" li-id="18">Anthropology Faculty Collections</li>
    <li parent-id="16" li-id="23">Shared Collections</li>
    <li parent-id="0" li-id="19">Center for Research on Vermont</li>
    <li parent-id="19" li-id="24">Collections for Testing</li>
    <li parent-id="24" li-id="25">Geology Department</li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $ul = $('ul');
    $ul.find('li[parent-id]').each(function () {
        $ul.find('li[parent-id=' + $(this).attr('li-id') + ']').wrapAll('<ul />').parent().appendTo(this)
    });
});

//to get li-id on double click
$('#orgCat li').dblclick(function(){
alert($(this).attr('li-id'));
})
```

**Problem** is
When double click on 'li' element its showing parents 'li-id' also but it should return only current list 'li-id'. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ddtjke0/)

Comment: add e.stopPropagation(); to stop the event from bubbling up to parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `e.stopPropagation` to stop event bubbling.

```
$('#orgCat li').dblclick(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
  alert($(this).attr('li-id'));
});
```

Check [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) for more information.

Comment: Could you resolve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819497/jquery-expand-only-selected-parent-list/44819557#44819557